# Animations rendered on Videos using AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool behaves differently in Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, avfoundation, avvideocomposition

I am trying to put some animated layers on top of  videos using the `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`. The speeds of the animations rendered are not consistent across all devices, ie I am forced to use different duration/fps for the
`CABasicAnimation` different devices like for iPhone 6 I have a duration of .5 while for iPod Touch 5G I am using .25 ,

```
composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool

                               videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

Anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: I ended up using GPUImageUIElement in the GPUImage framework. The Core Image rendering is too slow and hence not recommended here.

Comment: interesting. did you use swift or objective-c? the overlays came out crisp? overlays with coreanimationtool is rather grainy so if this produces crisper images it may be the way to go. also how large are the video sizes?